# magento 2 how to get children product sku or children product id using parent product id or sku

Tags: magento2, php, attributes, configurable-product, option

how to get children product SKU or children product id using parent product id or SKU
I have these details for particular options, here are 2 arrays and I need particular product id or sku

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value_index] => 5438
                [label] => Black
                [product_super_attribute_id] => 531
                [default_label] => Black
                [store_label] => Black
                [use_default_value] => 1
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [value_index] => 5907
                [label] => Silver
                [product_super_attribute_id] => 531
                [default_label] => Silver
                [store_label] => Silver
                [use_default_value] => 1
            )
    
    )
```

Note: I am using AMP so can not use Jquery

Comment: Is this configurable product or what array?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes it is configurable product

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
$configurableProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
     
    $_children = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configurableProduct);
    foreach ($_children as $child){
        echo $child->getID();
    }
```

**NOTE:** According to magento standard, do not allowed the use of Object Manager method, so implement the code by magento way.